# How to load a function of one component in another

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function in navbar which shows notifications and i want to run the same function in another component to show latest notifications but i am not sure about the process.

My navbar component,

```
 @Component({
    selector: 'header-Navbar',
    templateUrl: './app/navbar/navbar.html',
})
export class Navbar implements OnInit  {
    notification : any;
    header :any;
    constructor(public http: Http, fbld: FormBuilder, public config: Config,public router: Router) {
    ngOnInit(){
        this.getnotifications();
    }
    getnotifications(){
         var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        this.http.get(this.header + 'getcategorynotificationscountbyuserid/'+this.user.username, { headers: headers })
            .subscribe(
            response => {
                if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
                    this.notification = response.json().result;

                    }
                 else { 
                   if(response.json().result == 0){
                        this.notification == undefined;
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

My post componenet,

```
export class Posts {
  showseemore: any = true;
articleform: FormGroup;
commentform: FormGroup;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,public _navbar : Navbar,public  _notifications : GetNotifications, public router: Router, public http: Http, public config: Config, fbld: FormBuilder) {}
  //Here i want to load getnotifications() function of navbar component ////
```

Can any one please suggest help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one service which is shared between your `Navbar` and `Posts` component in which you can define Observable so that you can subscribe to that Observable from `Navbar` and perform some action when you receive some value from 'Posts'.

//common.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
  private notify = new Subject<any>();
  /**
   * Observable string streams
   */
  notifyObservable$ = this.notify.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  public notifyOther(data: any) {
    if (data) {
      this.notify.next(data);
    }
  }
}
```

//Navbar

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'header-Navbar',
  templateUrl: './app/navbar/navbar.html',
})
export class Navbar implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  notification : any;
  header :any;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(public http: Http, fbld: FormBuilder, public config: Config,public router: Router, private commonService: CommonService) {

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getnotifications();
  }

  getnotifications(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    this.http.get(this.header + 'getcategorynotificationscountbyuserid/' + this.user.username, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
        response => {
            if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
                this.notification = response.json().result;

                }
             else { 
               if(response.json().result == 0){
                    this.notification == undefined;
                }
            }
        });

    this.subscription = this.commonService.submitObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'get_notification') {
        console.log(res.value);
        // perform your other action from here
        this.getnotifications();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

//Posts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { CommonService } from './common.service';

@Component({
  selector   : 'posts',
  templateUrl : './posts.html'
})
export class Posts implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor( private commonService: CommonService ){
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.commonService.notifyOther({option: 'get_notification', value: 'From Navbar'});
  }
}
```

Comment: can you edit your service with my getnotifications function

Comment: I did'nt understood the code in navbar.ts can you please suggest me any articles

Comment: You can read about `Observable` and `Subject` on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html and Component interaction at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html